# Visual Studio 2022 Unnecessary using directives and undifined type error at the same time

Tags: vb.net, ide, visual-studio-2022, using

Is it just a Visual Studios bug?

I'm working with Visual Basic Project with Visual Studio Professional 17.4.3.
And it was no problem until last day when I open the solution,
Visual Studio showed a lot of errors with error code `BC30002: Type '<typename>' is not defined`.
But the sametime, the Type that errored was suggested by Visual Studio to remove `Imports` with warning code `IDE0005: Remove unnecessary using directives`.

The solution builds with no problem. It's just annoying to see..

I've tried Clean and Rebuilding, and deleting build files manually but I didn't worked.

Comment: I've seen similar things from time to time. I use ReSharper and I wasn't sure whether it was related to that. I don't really have a systematic way of getting around it.

Comment: Maybe check at the project references, look for any with a yellow warning Icon, sometimes the fix is simply to remove them and re-add them again

Comment: @jmcilhinney I wasn't using ReSharper but maybe somtimes Intellisense is showing error if there's some changes of build settings outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks for the idea! There was no error sign on the project references, but I did `delete reference -> Rebuild (Fails but fail right this time) -> rereference` and errors were gone! Maybe there is some cached infos or someting in Visual Studio.